# Novel featuring strange attractor and quest to find his father's spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Its a science fiction novel from the 90s. A man, down on his luck, trying to find the great spaceship his father captained. He has his father's pistol, which had something special about it - maybe the crest of the ship, or a special function for thwarting mutiny like a shotgun attachment or a pop-out blade. He teams up with some bureaucrat from Earth somehow, maybe kidnaps him? Anyway they become partners, and this guy has a replica of some 20thC pistol, like a Smith and Wesson.  And there is some kind of theme about aliens and a strange attractor...

Lots of action as he breaks into places to try and find the facts, being thwarted by a conspiracy.

I was in my teens when I read it, so might have been a young-adult novel.

Comment: Actually sounds like a CYOA novel I read in the 80s, although I don't remember the title or author.

Comment: Yes - from memory this was a trilogy but I can't remember the author or the series name. The bureaucrat already had or ended up with a belt with alien symbols. I've had a look on my shelves but can't find them so I must have sent them to the charity shop. I'll keep thinking and will post if I can remember the name or author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [Jinx on a Terran Inheritance](https://books.google.com/books/about/Jinx_on_a_Terran_Inheritance.html?id=2WQTnwEACAAJ)

Quoting from the book:

> All the tension and resentment in Alacrity—some of it dated back to Terra and the underhanded way he'd been framed and recruited—exploded. With a curse in some language that didn't sound quite human, showing his teeth and the whites of his eyes, he scrabbled back to the barrier, staying below the line of fire, and waited for a lull in the swarming of flechettes. Lying asprawl, he eased the muzzle of the Captain's Sidearm up, barely over the buttress, and let fly.
>
> Floyt, who'd been present on a previous firing, already had his fingers in his ears.
>
> The bulky old handgun overloaded the adit with thunder-flash, heat, and death. It had been designed for use against the dangers a vessel's skipper might face: boarding, riot, and mutiny. Its discharge was attended by almost overwhelming visible light and sonic energy.

and

> "The symbol in that file you took from Dincrist, for one thing—the file that started the row between you and Heart. It took me a second, but I placed the White Ship symbol. It's the same as the crests on the grips of the Captain's Sidearm, isn't it?"

My absolutely terrible earlier answer based on the belief it was a Choose Your Own Adventure novel:

Sounds like Choose Your Own Adventure #3, "Space and Beyond", https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/190949.Space_and_Beyond

Comment: What about this book fits the description?

Comment: Great find - I recognised it instantly from the description (hence my comment) but I just couldn't find the correct search terms. I will now have to decide if I want to re-purchase and re-read the `Alacrity FitzHugh & Hobart Floyt` trilogy.

Comment: Yes, well spotted. I have the book but hadn't made the connection. The *strange attractor* is mentioned in connection with the *causality harp*.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that is exactly the book. Somehow I didn't even realise it was part of a trilogy when I read it, I just thought it was cleverly treating the context as a given. Its available on Kindle too, so I'll give it a go tonight and see how it reads 20 years later.